# Add help_text to UserCreationForm

Tags: django

I'm using UserCreationForm in Django and I'm trying add help_text to the email field.

Here's the forms.py code:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email','username',)
        help_texts = {
            'email': 'Use your work email',
        }
```

I'm using Crispy Forms to render it and it isn't rendering the help_text.

As another approach, I tried adding this to the class:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CustomUserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['email'].help_text = 'hello'
```

But it didn't work either.

What am I missing?

EDIT: I realised I made a mistake with this question. This project had switched to using django-allauth, but left forms.py in the user app of this django project. Therefore none of the changes in these forms were having any effect. A check of the settings would've shown that it was using allauth.

Answer (score 0):

help_texts is not an attribute of the Meta class of a form. You can add the help text for the email field in your model, like this:

```
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, help_text='use your work email', blank=True, null=True)
```

Since email is not one of the fields of UserCreationForm (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm), setting the field via init will not work.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've added the additional line with help_text to my user model (and then ran the migration), but it didn't work. I can see in the migration that there is an AlterField for things like max_length, but nothing for help_text. My user model is based on AbstractUser, which I suspect is complicating things. There's no way in Django to add help_text at the form level? Or I guess I need to do it at the template level?

Comment: I see that you are using crispy forms. I think they use labels to describe the fields instead of help texts. You could try labels = {'email': 'Use your work email',} in your form; so just replace 'help_texts' with 'labels'.

Comment: Paul - I have to apologise. I realise that this project had switched over to using django-allauth, which means these forms were no longer being used (but had been left in the project). Completely my bad for not checking the auth setup earlier (still learning my way around django). Sorry about that and thank you for your input.